# How to get this json specific word from this array

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have this json and I would like to get only the Name from every array. How do I write it in python,

Currently, I have this li = [item.get(data_new[0]'id') for item in data_new]
where data_new is my json data.

```
   [
    {
        "id": "1687fbfa-8936-4b77-a7bc-123f9f276c49",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "status",
                "value": "rejected",
                "scope": "identity"
            },
            {
                "name": "created_ts",
                "value": "2020-06-25T16:22:07.578Z",
                "scope": "system"
            },
            {
                "name": "updated_ts",
                "value": "2020-07-08T12:43:09.361Z",
                "scope": "system"
            },
            {
                "name": "artifact_name",
                "value": "release-v10",
                "scope": "inventory"
            },
            {
                "name": "device_type",
                "value": "proddemo-device",
                "scope": "inventory"
            },
        ],
        "updated_ts": "2020-07-08T12:43:09.361Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "0bf2a1fe-6004-473f-88b7-aab061972115",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "status",
                "value": "rejected",
                "scope": "identity"
            },
            {
                "name": "created_ts",
                "value": "2020-07-01T16:23:00.631Z",
                "scope": "system"
            },
            {
                "name": "updated_ts",
                "value": "2020-07-08T17:41:16.45Z",
                "scope": "system"
            },
            {
                "name": "artifact_name",
                "value": "Module_logs_v7",
                "scope": "inventory"
            },
            {
                "name": "cpu_model",
                "value": "ARMv8 Processor",
                "scope": "inventory"
            },
            {
                "name": "device_type",
                "value": "device",
                "scope": "inventory"
            },
            {
                "name": "hostname",
                "value": "device004",
                "scope": "inventory"
            },
            {
                "name": "ipv4_br-d6eae8b3a339",
                "value": "172.0.0.1/18",
                "scope": "inventory"
             }
    ],

    "updated_ts": "2020-07-08T12:43:09.361Z"
}
]
```

This is the output snippet from my API and from this output I want to retrieve the value of the device whose name is hostname, as you can see that is the second last entry from this code where "name": "hostname"
So, I want to retrieve the value for that particular json only where the name will be "hostname", how can I do that.
Please guide me through.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{'id': '291ae0e5956c69c2267489213df4459d19ed48a806603def19d417d004a4b67e',
  'attributes': [{'name': 'ip_addr',
    'value': '1.2.3.4',
    'descriptionName': 'IP address'},
   {'name': 'ports', 'value': ['8080', '8081'], 'description': 'Open ports'}],
  'updated_ts': '2016-10-03T16:58:51.639Z'},
 {'id': '76f40e5956c699e327489213df4459d1923e1a806603def19d417d004a4a3ef',
  'attributes': [{'name': 'mac',
    'value': '00:01:02:03:04:05',
    'descriptionName': 'MAC address'}],
  'updated_ts': '2016-10-04T18:24:21.432Z'}]

descriptionName = []
    
for i in a:
    for j in i["attributes"]:
        for k in j:
            if k == "descriptionName":
                descriptionName.append(j[k])
```

One liner:

```
[j["descriptionName"] for j in i["attributes"] for i in a if "descriptionName" in j  ]
```

Output:

```
['IP address', 'MAC address']
```

**Update 1:**
To get all names

One liner code -

```
[j["name"] for j in i["attributes"] for i in a if "name" in j.keys()]
```

Output:

```
['status',
 'status',
 'created_ts',
 'created_ts',
 'updated_ts',
 'updated_ts',
 'artifact_name',
 'artifact_name',
 'cpu_model',
 'cpu_model',
 'device_type',
 'device_type',
 'hostname',
 'hostname',
 'ipv4_br-d6eae8b3a339',
 'ipv4_br-d6eae8b3a339']
```

To get value for which name is "hostname"

```
[j["value"] for j in i["attributes"] for i in a if "name" in j.keys() and j["name"] == "hostname"]
```

Output:

```
['device004', 'device004']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I tried the first code, but its giving me blank response or None None.

Comment: @NishadNazar both the codes are working fine for me.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question, please check it once. It's the same json format but data is different, more specific to what I exactly want. Sorry for the earlier inconvenience

Comment: @NishadNazar The json attached is invalid

Comment: Hi, I am getting "[j["value"] for j in i["attributes"]
NameError: name 'i' is not defined "  error

Comment: Hi @bigbounty, This is the last part, it will be great if you could help me with that error please.

Comment: @NishadNazar It's a list comprehension, you are writing 2 lines of `for` in one line. So, you have to first iterate on the list "a". Copy this whole thing and run - `[j["value"] for j in i["attributes"] for i in a if "name" in j.keys() and j["name"] == "hostname"]`

Comment: Hi @bigbounty, your solution helps me alot, just one modification Im trying, I would like to put two condition but it is giving [] blank, I need the "name" == "hostname" and "value" == "accepted" then get the accepted values frm this list. I tried [j["value"] for i in a for j in i["attributes"] if (j["value"] == "accepted") and (j["name"] == "hostname")] but It gave [].. What you think Im mising